# Justice League Rep Totals

Tags: discussion, league-of-justice, total-reputation

I know the totals are snapshot values and not real-time.  Are they raw totals, though, or do they exclude costs of bounties?  My thought is that they're just the raw totals, but I haven't gone through to match up someone who's offered a bounty with their total in the standings.

The argument could be made that the cost of bounties should not be considered in the league totals so I was just wondering if this was considered when the leagues were designed.  I don't care one way or the other and am not asking for it to change, just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are raw totals - and snapshots taken around 0:00 GMT every day.

It's fine as it is, bounties aren't used that often and considering them differently would complicate the system.

Answer (score 0):

There's clearly a delay of some unknown amount in updating the totals, since my "total reputation" tends to lag my actual reputation by a bit.

However, the "week reputation" always seems *way* off. It doesn't match my weekly reputation gain at all as displayed on my recent activity (i.e. "little envelope") page. And I have never offered (and rarely won) any bounties, so that doesn't explain it.

Maybe the two totals have very different cut-off values for "a week"? This discrepancy may be the culprit, as opposed to the exclusion of bounties.

Comment: Yeah, I've always attributed the difference in the weekly total to differing definitions of "week" between the sites.

Comment: Your "total reputation" is a snapshot taken daily.