# Should bounties be considered for /users or /leagues?

Tags: discussion

Consider this user who put a bounty up this week
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915/adam-davis?tab=reputation

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/users
Search for "Adam Davies"
It shows

```
Adam Davis
-475 week
```

Go to https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow
Search for "Adam Davies"
It shows

```
#8777 week rank
-480 week reputation
```

<sub>(why is there a difference? I thought they use the same data source)</sub>

What does the community feel about bounties being included in the [periodic] rep calculation for /users and /leagues?  I can understand bounties won being included, but not bounty offers.

Comment: Somewhat related with 2 thoughts on the topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63368/justice-league-rep-totals

Comment: I think the reason your second query didn't find him is that his name is "Davis", not "Davies". But that doesn't explain why your first query worked.

Comment: @mmyers - "oops"

Answer (score 1):

When I went to the last page of users and saw negative reputation I was confused for a bit, then realized I had "week" selected.  Then I noticed I was the second* to last person on that list. [image: #:-O]

Honestly, I think we should count bounties.  They change our reputation, and winning one is a valid way to appear in the leagues, even if only briefly.  I don't mind that spending reputation pushes one down in the leagues - bounties should hurt.

*<sub>And the only reason I'm not last is likely due to the oddity of the reputation recalc when it hit a suspended user.</sub>

Comment: That's an awesome smiley! Consider it stolen.

Comment: Is it a panic smiley?